# Why can't connect to mysql database from my php page?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

guys,I am developing a free hosting website in awardspce.net ,everything worked fine but when i am trying to connect a php page to mysql server,i get error.Actually any mysql_*
command gives me error but if i use mysqli instead of mysql, no error message is given but i am not sure that everything works fine.Can u tell me the difference between them?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABDZd.png)

Answer (score 0):

- PHP old mysql_* function are removed from PHP 7.*
- if you have PHP 5.* hosting, you must install or enable mysql extension
- install PHP 5.* mysql extension `apt-get install php5.6-mysql`, but better upgrade PHP app to use PDO or mysqli extensions

Comment: I am hosting my webpages in server of awardspace.net and using there database management system,so how can i run "apt-get install php5.6-mysql" command?
Or,can u tell if i use my_sqli instead of that,i will not face any problem?
thank u

Comment: On webhosting systems you must check configuration in the hosting's account. The `apt-get` will not work. You may add `<?php phpinfo();` script to webroot and check result in browser. There's info about all active PHP features on your hosting webserver.

Comment: update:i successfully solved the issue,i used mysqli_ instead of mysql_,then worked.